# How to Update only year from datetime in sqlserver based on Condition

Tags: sql-server

### In my DB has

### PoDate

[image]

I need to update this year is greater than 2015 as 2015

Answer (score 2):

```
update tab
set date_col = DATEFROMPARTS ( 2015, datepart(mm,date_col), datepart(dd,date_col))
where datepart(year,date_col) > 2015
```

try this.

Answer (score 1):

`DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` can solve this easily:

```
UPDATE UnnamedTable SET PoDate = DATEADD(year,
                                    DATEDIFF(year,PoDate,'20150101'),
                                 PoDate)
WHERE PoDate >= '20160101'
```

The logic being that the number of (whole) years difference between a date in 2015 and the future date should be subtracted from the date. By Swapping the arguments to `DATEDIFF` so that the later date comes first, I don't need an explicit `-` to negate the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select '2015-12-01 00:00:00.000' as date_col
into #temp
union 
Select '2016-12-01 00:00:00.000'
union
Select '2017-12-01 00:00:00.000'
union 
Select '2018-12-01 00:00:00.000'
union
Select '2019-12-01 00:00:00.000'

update #temp
set date_col = dateadd(yyyy,datediff(yyyy,date_col,'2015-01-01'),date_col) 
from #temp
```